# How to treat strings as html tags in dash framework?

Tags: plotly-dash

I am trying to display the string that the user defined with html tagging. Is that possible?

Here is the sample string:

```
"<h2>Introduction</h2><p>This document provides a guide to help with the important task of choosing the correct Apple.</p>"
```

When passing it to dash, I want dash to display/treat it as html tags, i.e., `<h2>` and `<p>`. I tried to remove the quotes using this, .replace('""',''), but still dash treats it as string.

Has anybody encounter this?

Answer (score 0):

In Dash, there is an option to use the following commands to use [html tages](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/h1):

```
from dash import html

html.Div([
    html.H1('Hello Dash'),
    html.Div([
        html.H2('Introduction'),
        html.P("This document provides a guide to help with the important task of choosing the correct Apple.")
    ])
])
```